# Disable docker swarm mode (Docker cloud)

Tags: docker, docker-cloud

How can I disable docker `Swarm mode` in `Docker cloud`? There used to be a way to do it through dashboard (toggle to switch between cluster and swarm mode) but it has disappeared overnight.

Is there a way to do it via CLI?

> After

[image]

> Before
>   [image]

I've checked the docs and can't find anything relevant, there's also nothing in account settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible way to disable swarm mode is to send an email to the docker cloud support. https://forums.docker.com/t/disable-swarm-mode/29336/3

Comment: @yament it says it should stay the same for existing users or am i missing something. I'm not a new user

Answer (score 1):

Docker is retiring cluster management on Docker Cloud today. I only see cloud registry and continuous integration services on the site, cluster management is not available any more. Swarm mode is also gone.

[image]

The info bar on the top of the screenshot takes you here http://success.docker.com/article/cloud-migration and here https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/migration/, please see the details on these pages.

Answer (score 0):

It's mentioned in the After Image
See a toggle button before **Swarm mode** (left side in the image, right after DOCKER CLOUD)

[image]

Comment: Sorry @fly2matrix, there was a typo in the descriptions :) Should be other way around